# How to display project names on Cruisecontrol dashboard?

Tags: java, build, cruisecontrol

we want to evaluate Cruisecontrol 2.8.4 for our build process. It comes with a nice dashboard with symbols on the frontpage representing a project and the status.

What is missing is the name of the project, only if one hovers over the rectangle it shows the project name in a tooltip.

Is there any way to display the name of the project constantly on the main dashboard page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible:
go to \cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4\webapps\dashboard\WEB-INF\vm\latest_builds

Edit file latest_builds_bar_partial.vm

from Line

```
<a href="$href" id="${buildCmd.build.projectName}_bar_link"></a>
```

to :

```
<a href="$href" id="${buildCmd.build.projectName}_bar_link" style="text-align:left;color:#black;font-weight:bold">${buildCmd.build.projectName}</a>
```

then change in cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/webapps/dashboard/css the file daschboard_tab.css
just in the line .bar change width which do you want. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the XSL which renders the Dashboard.

To be honest, if plugins and customisation are your thing, consider #Hudson.